# How to transition from IPv4 to IPv6 for a domain?

Tags: nginx, dns, hosting, ipv6, ipv4

I currently have a domain which has the following DNS record:

```
A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (ipv4)
```

And my nginx vhost looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.com;
}
```

1. How can I use an IPv6 ip address that my host provides instead of the IPv4?
2. Are both records (both an ipv4 and ipv6) needed for old browsers to work?
3. Are there any other things to look out for to make sure that email deliverability doesn't get effected if switching from a v4 to v6?

Sorry for the beginner questions.

**PS.** The reason for doing this is because my host only provides 1 ipv4 address but 16 v6 addresses and I'd like to host each domain to their own dedicated ip address.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/421447/126632

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Listen 80; try doing something like this

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
```

or

```
Listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
```

and the xxx will be your ipv4 or you can try using ipv6 and see does that work also